# Possible to switch between admin view and author view?

Tags: author, admin-menu

The wordpress admin dashboard can be a bit daunting for "normal" wp authors.

Is it possible for users who need admin privileges to only see the simpler author view, but be able to switch to the full admin dashboard when required?

I understand we could simply create another author account for them. Or use a plugin to create a unique dashboard for each user type.

But is it possible to switch between admin / author dashboards at will, without having to log out and then back in again as a different user?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just easier and much more secure to have an admin user which **is not** an author, and use plugins like https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-switching/ to switch if there is something that can't be solved with having two browsers open at the same time ;)